# R Markdown not displaying plotly graphics

Tags: r, markdown, plotly

I am using Rstudio Version 1.1.447. on a Dell Latitude E5470 using Windows 10. I am trying to create a presentation for an assignment using R markdown and knittr and ioslides. The resultant presentation has a complete black page instead of the graph. The graph however does display in Rstudio if I run the code on its own outside of R markdown.

Here is my code:

````
```{r, echo = TRUE, include=FALSE}
library("plotly")
library("ggplot2")
library("datasets")
data("state")

x <- state.area
y <- state.x77[,1]*1000
z <- state.x77[,5]
fac <- state.division

newdf <- as.data.frame(cbind(state.area, state.x77[,1]*1000, state.x77[,5], state.division))
colnames(newdf) <- c("Area", "Population", "Murder", "Division")

p <-plot_ly(newdf, 
            x="Area", 
        y="Population",
        z="Murder",
        type="scatter3d", 
        mode="markers", 
        color="Division")
p
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Try the same but removing the `{r, echo = TRUE, include=FALSE}` and replace it with just `{r}`.

Here is a complete working answer.

````
---
title: "Plotly in Markdown Example"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library("plotly")
library("ggplot2")
library("datasets")

data("state")

x <- state.area
y <- state.x77[,1]*1000
z <- state.x77[,5]
fac <- state.division
```

## Plot title goes here

Awesome comments about plot output goes here:

```{r}

newdf <- as.data.frame(cbind(state.area, state.x77[,1]*1000, state.x77[,5],     state.division))
colnames(newdf) <- c("Area", "Population", "Murder", "Division")

p <-plot_ly(newdf, 
            x="Area", 
        y="Population",
        z="Murder",
        type="scatter3d", 
        mode="markers", 
        color="Division")
p
```
````